# File Extension - Use it for files. (.Mp3 and .Wav)

Tags: java, if-statement, audio, switch-statement, jpanel

I manage to make a program that could understand mp3 in Java (by jaco.mp3 jar) and it works. However this means that the .Wav files doesn't work of course. So I fixed so that I could use the Wav but the problem will then be that I can't use the mp3 then. so I found out that I could use the File Extension and my idea was to make like this:

If the last 3 or 4 letters ends with .mp3 then do the mp3 method, if its .Wav then to Wave method. but I don't really know how to manage it together, I was thinking more like a Switch-statement. But I really never worked with File extension before and could need som help with that!

However this is my mp3 method that is like this right now:

```
public void Choose() {
        String userDir = System.getProperty("user.home");
        JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser(userDir +"/Desktop");

        int returnValue = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
        if (returnValue == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            File selectedFile = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
            System.out.println(selectedFile.getName());

            mp3_player =  new MP3Player(selectedFile);
            lblPlayURL.setText(selectedFile.getName());
        }
    }
}
```

as you can see I have a JFileChooser where I pick the song I want of course and I still want to do it, only that the different is now it should work both as .Wav and .mp3. But I don't really know how to go further with it. so any help is needed from you guys! :)

Before people is trying to give any suggestions from a thread that says Playing .Wav and .Mp3. I would just say first that I have read it and there is only answers about each of them, Only mp3 or the .Wav. not both. so thats why I created this thread because I need help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perhaps check if the file path ends with MP3 or WAV and have an if statement to run different programs depending on the condition.

This can be done like so:

```
String ext = selectedFile.getPath();

if(ext.endsWith(".wav"))
{
    // A WAV file was chosen
}
else if(ext.endsWith(".mp3"))
{
    // An MP3 file was chosen
}
else
{
    // Something else was chosen
}
```

EDIT: This method together with Bogdan's answer is probably your best bet.

Comment: Hmm, the issue i'm having right now I don't know how I can manage to make it so it checks if the file path has a end of mp3 or Wav

Comment: @WeInThis I've added that now, sorry.

Comment: Goddamnet! Having some issues with Wav right now haha.

Comment: Im getting `Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException` :/ What could that mean

Answer (score 0):

Add `FileFilter` rules to your `JFileChooser` to match **.mp3** and **.wav** files:

```
fileChooser.addChoosableFileFilter(new FileTypeFilter(".mp3", "MP3 Files"));
fileChooser.addChoosableFileFilter(new FileTypeFilter(".wav", "WAV files"));
```

[How to add file filter for JFileChooser dialog](http://www.codejava.net/java-se/swing/add-file-filter-for-jfilechooser-dialog).

Comment: Hmm, What does this do if I might ask :)?

Comment: Oh. but the problem is to make it work aswell. I mean so it comes out sound of it aswell :)

Comment: Could you help me by adding .Wav maybe?